# Access div outside the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change the style of `.box1` by clicking on `.box3`?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box3").click(function() {
    $(this).parents().find('.box1').css('border', '1px solid red');
  });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box1 {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box box2">Box2
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('.container').find('.box1').css('border', '1px solid red');`

Comment: @Hazonko -- didn't work https://jsfiddle.net/v6z5yqyw/5/

Comment: look the console, you have to include the jquery. <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

Comment: You neglected to include jQuery in your fiddle. Do that and it seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/y5w1twsk/. Also, your document ready handler syntax is also wrong. No need for the `()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parent()` and `prev()` jQuery methods like below example.

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box3").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev('.box1').css('border', '1px solid red');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box1 {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box box2">Box2
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent()` without the `s`

```
$(function(){
    $(".box3").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.box1').css('border', '1px solid red');
    });
})();
```

or use `parents` with `selector` argument `parents('.container')`

```
$(function(){
    $(".box3").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.container').find('.box1').css('border', '1px solid red');
    });
})();
```

Comment: @Rafel-- i did add jquery. I think i didn't update. Here is the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/v6z5yqyw/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with just Javascript....

```
var box3Div = document.querySelector("div.box3");
box3Div.onclick = function(){
    this.parentElement.previousSibling.style.border = "1px solid red";
}
```